# Employable javaEE framework?

Tags: ejb

first post,

I am searching for the most employable java framework and skills for server side dev.

I am ok with core java but would like to learn enterprise skills. I am considering buying an elearning course that uses ejb3 and jsf2. Are these skills employable or would I be better advised to learn another framework such as spring on completion of the course?

I have tried looking at job specs in my area but there does not seem to be a common denominator. Could someone advise the most employable framework that employers would consider in the absence of their advertised requirement?

Thanks for reading and any help appreciated.

Comment: This question would be more suitable on programmers.stackexchange.com, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't waste my money on an EJB3 course.  There are enough on-line resources and books where you don't have to sign up for anything.  You just have to be disciplined enough to follow through.

Most employable?  Pick one, it doesn't matter.  Download JBOSS or WebLogic or Glassfish and have at it.

I prefer Spring myself.